# How do I resolve the error while installing tensorRT

Tags: python, tensorrt

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tensorrt : Depends: libnvinfer8 (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libnvinfer-plugin8 (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libnvparsers8 (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libnvonnxparsers8 (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libnvinfer-bin (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libnvinfer-dev (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libnvinfer-plugin-dev (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libnvparsers-dev (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libnvonnxparsers-dev (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libnvinfer-samples (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Then I tried to install `python3-libnvinfer-dev`

```
(atms-env) (base) rajesh@radi:~/projects$ sudo apt-get install python3-libnvinfer-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-libnvinfer-dev : Depends: python3-libnvinfer (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libnvinfer-dev (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libnvinfer-plugin-dev (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libnvparsers-dev (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libnvonnxparsers-dev (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I tried to install `python3-libnvinfer`

```
(atms-env) (base) rajesh@radi:~/projects$ sudo apt-get install python3-libnvinfer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-libnvinfer : Depends: libnvinfer8 (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libnvinfer-plugin8 (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libnvparsers8 (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libnvonnxparsers8 (= 8.6.1.6-1+cuda11.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I tried to install python3-libnvinfer

```
(atms-env) (base) rajesh@radi:~/projects$ sudo apt-get install libnvinfer8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvinfer8 : Depends: libcublas.so.11 but it is not installable or
                        libcublas-11-1 but it is not installable or
                        libcublas-11-0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

CUDA 11.2 is installed and the file libcublas.so.11 is in /usr/local/cuda/lib64, which is in my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I read in some other thread that it may look for this in my venv, site-packages. I also checked and it is there in the site-packages....nvidia/cublas

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}$
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/rajesh/projects/atms-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nvidia/cublas${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

Also tried with the `LD_library_PATH` wihout the python-site-packages ... path but same error.

```
(atms-env) (base) rajesh@radi:~/projects$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Feb_14_21:12:58_PST_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.152
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29618528_0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. I did two things, I am not sure which fixed it, though.

First: I installed cuda11.2 with update 2 (I do not remember if I originally installed with update 2)
Downloaded the debian file and installed it.

Second: I re-installed the tensorrt from the .deb that I had downloaded previously.
then
cd /var/nv-tensorrt-local-repo......
Installed the remaining from this directory.

sudo apt-get install tensorrt

sudo apt-get install python3-libnvinfer-dev

Was able to verify the installation with
dpkg-query -W tensorrt

Not sure if it was CUDA11.2 update 2 or cd into /var/nv-t.... that helped.